# strapi to rebuild the db schema nodejs to update swagger documentaion

Tags: node.js, swagger, swagger-ui, strapi

I started working with `strapi`, so I create an app using blog template.

And strapi version `3.6.8`

To use the swagger I added documentation module using

```
yarn add documentation
```

From the admin panel I renamed some content types and removed un wanted ones. Now when I see the swagger it still shows the old entries there.

From the admin panel under Documentation option I tried `Regenerate` and the `Update`, even restarted the server. But still it is showing old content types.

And even for every schema it has created the duplicate schema by prefixing the new keyword like

```
Writer
NewWriter
```

is there any way to solve this?

Comment: Which version of Strapi are you using?

Comment: Well, ideally in such cases what we do is we manually delete the tables from `phpMyAdmin` or `pgAdmin` and let strapi generate the proper tables on it's own. Also, before doing such a thing make sure you don't have unnecessary models in your API folder. It also, happens that some times strapi is not able to alter the table columns on it's own. So we just delete the columns from the table so that they are auto-generated. **Additionally, make sure you have `autoMigration` enabled in the `config/database.js` file.**